# Hosting Windows Forms user control in asp.net web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, user-controls

I have created one Windows Forms User Control and I need to put it in a web page. I have seen many links:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191631/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052604-1.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewdownum/archive/2006/01/10/controlinbrowserintroduction.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx

But it is not working.

To put that WIndows Form User Control in Web Page. I have written following Code in web page.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <object id="MyWinControl" 
         classid="http:VideoShareUserControl.dll#VideoShareUserControl.UserControl1"
         height="100%" 
         width="100%" VIEWASTEXT />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

But its not working.

So please provide me any solution.

Comment: what does it mean not working?

Comment: i want to load it in asp.net page. So i have used <object> tag. But its not displaying the control...

Comment: If you look at your webage html source, is there anything showing where your control should be? Or is there just an empty div?

Comment: in Firefox it is just an empty div. But in Internet Explorer its showing like a frame...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot to set some options:

1. set register for com interop from build menu in project property page.
2. your control's code should be something like that (do not forget Comvisible and Guid):

Code:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace WindowsFormsControlLibrary1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("CD46781D-B691-4287-B802-C9E2540AF08A")]
    [ProgId("WpfComHostDemo.WinformHostUserControl")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {      
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Environment.UserName+" "+Environment.MachineName+" "+
                            Environment.OSVersion);
        }
    }
}
```

3. in your html or asp.net page use this code :

   `<object classid="clsid:CD46781D-B691-4287-B802-C9E2540AF08A" />`
4. put uour control dll in the root of your web site
5. there is no need to add it as a reference.